# Twitter4j stream tweets according to user's location on profile

Tags: java, twitter, stream, twitter4j, tweets

I'm using the twitter4j library to stream tweets from a particular location. The API is retrieving tweets corresponding to the passed longitude and latitude values according to the tagged location of the tweet itself. Is there a way to make twitter4j search according also to the location on the profile of the user who posted the tweet?
The current code resembles the following:

```
    FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery();
    double[][] locations = {{30,40},{70,100}};
    filterQuery.locations(locations);
    twitterStream.filter(filterQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to filter on a user's profile location using Twitter's basic streaming API. The only way you'd be able to do that would be via the commercial Gnip PowerTrack API, with the geolocation enrichment.